# JavaScript: Page reload from javascript using setting headers

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I am doing login using JavaScript Ajax(POST) call(which gives me access tokens). After login, in success method I want to redirect user to dashboard, using a page reload(which document.location.href does). While redirecting to dashboard, I want to set access tokens in headers. How can we achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('custom-header', 'value');
```